# InnoDB: Changing the length of a VARCHAR primary Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, varchar

I have a table in InnoDB which uses a VARCHAR based ForeignKey:

```
CREATE TABLE `portal_equity` (
   `isin` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
    ....,
    PRIMARY KEY (`isin`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Another table has a ForeignKey constraint to that table:

```
CONSTRAINT `equity_id_refs_isin_2581bb1d` FOREIGN KEY (`equity_id`) REFERENCES `portal_equity` (`isin`)
```

I needed to change the length of the primary key VARCHAR column, so I did. Now I keep getting the following integrity error every time I want to reference a row from the "portal_equity" table where the isin exceeds the original length of 12.

> Foreign key constraint fails for table `investtor`.`portal_equitypastvalue`:
>      CONSTRAINT `equity_id_refs_isin_7eed44e7` FOREIGN KEY (`equity_id`) REFERENCES `portal_equity` (`isin`)
>      Trying to add in child table, in index `portal_equitypastvalue_equity_id_6e7526e1` tuple:
>      DATA TUPLE: 3 fields;
>      0: len 12; hex 304c55303332333133343030; asc 0LU032313400;; 1: len 3; hex 8fb578; asc   x;; 2: len 4; hex 8001398a; asc   9 ;;
>
> But in parent table `investtor`.`portal_equity`, in index `PRIMARY`, the closest match we can find is record:
>      PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 9; compact format; info bits 0
>      0: len 13; hex 304c5530333233313334303036; asc 0LU0323134006;; 1: len 6; hex 000000005139; asc     Q9;; 2: len 7; hex 800000002d0110; asc     -  ;; 3: len 4; hex 61736466; asc asdf;; 4: len 4; hex 80000050; asc    P;; 5: len 3; hex 736466; asc sdf;; 6: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;; 7: len 2; hex 4144; asc AD;; 8: len 0; hex ; asc ;;

Do I need to regenerate all foreignkey constraints? That seems rather excessive. Is this behavior/error documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to regenerate all foreignkey constraints?

Yes.

> That seems rather excessive.

If you change the datatype of a primary key field, it seems natural to me that you the datatype of the foreign key fields (and their respective indexes and constraints) also need to be changed.

Although the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) states 'The length of string types need not be the same', logical sense dictates that the foreign key field should at least be as long as any data you want to store in it.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, the FOREIGN KEY constraints itself did not need to be updated. Instead, the actual fields in those child tables storing the primary key still had the old length, something I completely missed, which is kind of stupid. I partly blame the ORM, which automatically creates these foreign key fields and kind of kept them off my radar.